# Install Ruby 2.4.1 from source code at Linux

Tags: ruby, linux

Linux version is: 2.6.18-308.el5

A Ruby version 1.8.5 has already been installed on it

My commands:

> ./configure --prefix=/home/user_a/local

make

```
Csh:$ make
CC = gcc
LD = Id
LDSHARED = gcc -shared
CFLAGS = -03 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -
Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable
-Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -W
implicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -std=gnu99
XCFLAGS = -D_F0RTIFY_S0URCE=2 -fstack-protector -fvisibility=hidden -DRU
BY_EXP0RT -fPIE ~ ~
CPPFLAGS = -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-linux -I./include -I. -I./enc/uni
code/9.0.0
DLDFLAGS = -fstack-protector -pie
SOLIBS = -Igmp
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even fo「 MERCHANTABILITY 〇「 FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
generating id.h
./tool/generic_erb.rb:31: syntax error
if (/\A\e\[.*m\z/ =〜10.popenC'tput smso11, err: 10: :NULL, &:read> rescue
nil)
/s
./tool/generic_erb.rb:31: syntax error
if (/\A\e\[.*m\z/ =〜10.popenC'tput smso11, err: 10: :NULL, &:read> rescue
nil)
/s
./tool/generic_erb.rb:31: syntax error
if (/\A\e\[.*m\z/ =〜10.popenC'tput smso11, err: 10: :NULL, &:read> rescue
nil)
./tool/generic_erb.rb:38: syntax error
make: *** [id.h] Error 1
```

Command make raise Error:

[Command Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCBbA.png)

It is that mean Ruby need an installed version when installing a new version...?
I'm not the administrator, do not have a permission to remove 1.8.5
How to walk around this?

Thanks

Comment: How old is your computer? Ruby `1.8.5` was [released in **2006**](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2006/08/29/ruby-1-8-5-released/); I've been working with the language for years, and never even seen an installation this old! Even the [download link is dead](https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/ruby-1.8.5.tar.gz).

Comment: Anyway... Important question: Is there a good reason why you are installing ruby from source like this? It's normal to install multiple ruby versions via [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation) or [rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install).

Comment: Thanks Tom. The 1.8.5 version is  the Linux system default version, Linux version is old. The computer is off-line, can not access internet...

Comment: Is that the full error message? (It's very vague...) Can you post it here as *text*, rather than a link to an image?

Comment: That is the full log. I have edited it in question

Comment: @bo.meng: the text doesn't match the picture (and the error messages don't make sense, as a result). Did you run the screenshot through OCR? Post correct text.

Comment: I'm guessing @bo.meng used OCR for convenience because the computer has no internet connection.

Comment: @TomLord: yet the picture appears to be of screenshot quality.   ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

In case of doubts about compiling a Ruby version, you might be better off using a version manager, like [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or [rvm](https://rvm.io/).

If this is not the case, it should be as simple as downloading from [the official source](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) and running:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

And in case you want another dir than default (/usr/local), you could just pass, as you mention, `--prefix=DIR` to `./configure`.